# How to use Collections.binarySearch for ArrayList<List<String>> arr in java

Tags: java, string, arraylist, binary-search

I have an `ArrayList<List<String>>` and im trying to use the built-in binary search in the collection but I always come up with an error

`int index = Collections.binarySearch(arraylistdata, id);`

Where **arraylistdata** is my `ArrayList` of `List<String>`.

Comment: Show us your code please, Cannot understand the type of id or type of arraylistdata

Comment: so your arraylistdata declaration is `List<List<String>> arraylistdata`? Collections do not support that, you may have provide your own comparator

Comment: Take a look at Example #5 in this link https://www.javatpoint.com/java-collections-binarysearch-method

Comment: Main problem: `List` is does not implement `Comparable`. Potential other problem: `binarySearch` only works on *sorted* collections.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```java
public class CollectionsTest {
    
    @Test
    void test() {
        List<String> list = List.of("a", "b", "c");
        int index = Collections.binarySearch(list, "b");
        Assertions.assertEquals(1, index);
    }
}
```

This works fine, but you need to known that `Collections#binarySearch` accept a `List<? extends Comparable<? super T>>` as its first parameter.

While in your case, `ArrayList<List<String>>` does not match the requirement , as `List<String>` or `List<?>` itself is not a `Comparable` object.